# WPF - UI not updating but debug.writeline update correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, progress-bar

Good Morning i have been trying to create an updater for my apps and have nearly got a finalised result however i cant seem to get the UI to report the progress i have setup Onpropertychanged events and async tasks for the download but wont reflect in the ui

code i have for the download,

```
private async Task DownloadUpdateAsync(string url, string destinationPath)
{
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await client.GetAsync(url, 
    HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var totalBytes = response.Content.Headers.ContentLength ?? 0;
    var readBytes = 0L;
    var buffer = new byte[8192];
    using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(destinationPath, FileMode.Create, 
    FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                if (bytesRead == 0)
                {
                    await Task.Yield();
                    break;
                }

                await fileStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                readBytes += bytesRead;

                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
                    DownloadProgress = (int)((readBytes / (float)totalBytes) * 100);
                    Process = DownloadProgress.ToString(); // Convert to string
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DownloadProgress));
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Process)); // Notify property change for Process
                    Debug.WriteLine(Process); // Print the Process value
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

i been trying to get the progress bar to work however did notice the debug.writeline worked so to rule out it being the int cast i did the same for a textbox however still does not update

the Int setup

```
        public int DownloadProgress
    {
        get => downloadProgress;
        set
        {
            if (downloadProgress != value)
            {
                downloadProgress = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DownloadProgress));
            }
        }
    }
```

have set a breakpoint line on onpropertyChanged event and it does received the updated value but does not reflect this in the UI

XAML

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewmodel:UpdateViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>


<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CustomProgressBar" TargetType="ProgressBar">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#DCA3FF"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#7C8093"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>



<Grid>
    <Border Background="#7C8093" CornerRadius="5">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="An update is available."/>
            <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="Change Log: update test"/>
            <Button  Content="Update Now" Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}" />
            <ProgressBar Height="20" Value="{Binding DownloadProgress, Mode=OneWay}" />
            <TextBlock Width="700" Text="{Binding Process, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <Button Content="Test Progress" Command="{Binding TestProgressCommand}" />
            

        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
    
    

</Grid>
```

i am quite sure i have this to a tee i have searched around and even used chatgpt before writing on here but still having issues with it reflecting the progress of the download

the output window with proof that the debug gets the updates and showing download process
[image: OutPutOfDownload]

i have tryied to provide as much info as i can about the issue.

Comment: How do you start a download? Be aware that the view is bound to the view model instance that is created in XAML. In order to use that instance in code behind, you would have to access the view's DataContext like `var vm = (UpdateViewModel)DataContext;`

Comment: As Clemes implies, ensure that you don't work on two different instances of the `UpdateViewModel` (e.g., one created in XAML and one in C#). The `Task.Run` is redundant and only wastes resources and causes unnecessary overhead and should be removed. You are using the async stream API. Wrapping those async calls into a `Task.Run` is only degrading the performance. The `Dispatcher.Invoke` call is the same: redundant and only creating unnecessary overhead and must be removed.

Comment: Setting properties or the `PropertyChanged` event to be more precise, will automatically marshalled to the UI thread by the binding engine. You are not allowed to reference a `DispatcherObject` like a control from any other thread than the dispatcher thread that the `DispatcherObject` was created on. However, this constraint does not apply to properties that the `DispatcherObject` may bind to. Relevant is the thread that the `PropertyChanged` event is raised on and this is taken care of by the binding engine (to raise the event on the correct dispatcher thread).

Comment: In addition, the `OnPropertyChanged` calls inside the dispatcher callback are redundant too as the event is already raised by the property. Raising it twice can also lead to bad performance or unexpected behavior.

Comment: @elfenliedtopfan5: How exactly do you call the `DownloadUpdateAsync` method?

Answer (score 0):

One issue with your current usage of `ProgressBar` is that you're assigning a value out of 100, but not setting the `Maximum` property on the bar ([which defaults to `1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.rangebase.maximum?view=windowsdesktop-8.0#system-windows-controls-primitives-rangebase-maximum)). This would cause the progress bar to appear at 100% for any value of 1 or above, giving the appearance of not updating.

Instead simply try this:

```
 <ProgressBar Maximum="100" 
              Height="20" 
              Value="{Binding DownloadProgress, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Additionally (though unlikely to be the cause of your issue), the comments to your question are correct; you don't need to use `Task.Run` here and, if you don't use `Task.Run`, you also don't need to use `Dispatcher.Invoke`. And you don't need `Task.Yield`; just `break` when 'bytesRead' is `0`.